How to get access to all download statistics
I'm using Jfrog Artifactory to store python packages. It would be of huge help to get access to all download statistics, i.e know who has downloaded the package, when, which version?
I see Jfrog is collecting and displaying number of downloads in their interface and "last downloaded by", my guess is everything is stored behind the hood.

I've been looking through the whole product and found no dashboards to visualise downloads statistics at the user level.
I also investigated API calls to jfrog and the best I found was returning the same insights (number of downloads, last downloaded by): https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/file-statistics


The preferred way for users/admins to search for binary statistics is using AQL (Artifactory Query Language) together with the JFrog CLI.
In addition, as you mentioned dashboards, JFrog doesn't have dashboards for that however, it does offer a range of integrations with Log Analytic tools (i.e Grafana, New-Relic, DataDog, SumoLogic) that can help with showing the data on dashboards.

Thank you for your answer. I've used AQL via curl commands, but the best I found was to once again getting aggregated results per versions (e.g 50 downloads for a version, but not the name of eah user who has downloaded it).
I've tried many AQL .include function options (https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/display-specific-fields)

In the AQL documentation (https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/aql-entities-and-fields) you can see under "Stat" what can be returned. The documentation clarifies that only the last user who downloaded it will be shown. In case you would want to see improvement for this capability you can open a feature request here (https://jfrog.atlassian.net/projects/RTFACT/issues/?filter=allissues)
